# async_write method error

Tags: c++, boost-asio

```
void Chat::Send(uint8_t* buffer, int length){
        boost::asio::async_write(socket_,boost::asio::buffer(buffer,length),
            boost::bind(&Chat:Send, this,boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}
```

it should work like [this tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/example/chat/chat_server.cpp). But when I try to build the project I get the following errors

```
Error   1   error C2825: 'F': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'    e:\boost_1_46_1\boost_1_46_1\boost\bind\bind.hpp    69
Error   2   error C2039: 'result_type' : is not a member of '`global namespace''    e:\boost_1_46_1\boost_1_46_1\boost\bind\bind.hpp    69
Error   3   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'type'    e:\boost_1_46_1\boost_1_46_1\boost\bind\bind.hpp    69
Error   4   error C2208: 'boost::_bi::type' : no members defined using this type    e:\boost_1_46_1\boost_1_46_1\boost\bind\bind.hpp    69
Error   5   error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation e:\boost_1_46_1\boost_1_46_1\boost\bind\bind.hpp    69
```

I am not even using 'F' why it's keep saying 'F': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'?

Comment: `void Connection::Send(uint8_t* buffer, int length){

 boost::asio::async_write(socket_,boost::asio::buffer(buffer,length),
            boost::bind(&Connection::handler, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

void Connection::handler(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred ){
  }
`

i made it like that and it worked , but is that the right solve for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

```
boost::bind(&Chat:Send, this,boost::asio::placeholders::error));
               ^^^^^^
```

should be

```
boost::bind(&Chat::Send, this,boost::asio::placeholders::error));
               ^^^^^^
```

note the scope resolution operator for class `Chat`. The compiler errors that can be encountered when using `boost::bind` are very confusing.